# React Native blank screen with no errors?

Tags: react-native

I am new to React Native.
I am using Android Emulator from Android Studio, and I did not change anything at all from any .json file... Whenever the emulator is running it's always a blank screen...  It does not display any single error by the way...

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
    </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default App;
```

Comment: is emulator working? you have whole black screen?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Just press R two times... that simple, yes...

Comment: If it's not working for you too bad, I resolved the issue that way.  It's a hot reload bug and pressing R multiple times helped to reload.